# What does psql -d postgres do?

Tags: postgresql

What is the `-d` for and why do you need to type `postgres` when the `psql` already stands for postgres?

```
psql -d postgres
```

Comment: `psql --help` [or the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) will tell you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
psql -d postgres
```

here `-d` stands for database name and hence `postgres` is your database name.

You can open the terminal by only typing `psql`, Above statement will do two things for you

- Open psql terminal
- Connect you to `postgres` db

For more psql options you can refer https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks @satendra, just wanted to confirm that `postgres` could've been any name right?

Comment: It would need to be an existing database name still.